# Weird input box bug PC safari

Tags: jquery, html, inputbox

There is an input box in my HTML5 game. I want to use it on both mobile and PC so I included both mobile jquery and PC jquery at the same time.

```
<input id="searcher" data-role="none" type="search" placeholder="Search Friends"
                   style="position:absolute; background-color:white; display:block;">
```

However, there is bug when it runs on PC Safari. When I input text in the input box, there will be a cross appearing at the right side of the input box. If I click on the cross, then all other parts of the page stop responding to mouse clicks. No matter where you click on the viewport the input box will get focus, just like you clicked on the input box.

I have no idea why this happens. Is there a way to fix this bug (Which I think is a event propagate bug) or just not display the cross sign?

How the search function work? I will catch the the "input" event of the input box and get the string in the input box. Then pass the string to a light weight search engine called Fuse. The UI will be refreshed according to the search results:

```
    $("#searcher").on("input", function () {
        var text = $("#searcher").val();
        // If the text is empty, hide the keyboard and blur the search text box.
        if (text === "") $("#searcher").blur().attr("placeholder", "Search Friends");
        // Do a search in middle layer.
        fuseDoSearch(text);
        // Call this function to refresh the UI.
        refreshUI();
    }).focus(function () {
        // When obtaining the focus, remove the place holder string.
        $("#searcher").attr("placeholder", "");
    }).blur(function () {
        // When losing focus, fill the place holder string.
        $("#searcher").attr("placeholder", "Search Friends");
    }).bind(mobile ? "touchstart" : "mousedown", function() {
        // There is a bug in mobile devices that you have to hold the input
        // box for a while to get focus of the input box. So use this to force
        // the input box to get focus when clicked on.
        $("#searcher").focus();
    });
```

And these are all the event listeners I use.

Comment: How does your search function work? If it hangs on an empty string, that would be your problem.

Comment: What code do have? 
Any EventListeners for the input field? 
Do you get any errors in the Console?

Comment: @minitech I have edited the question description. Thanks!

Comment: @Mathias I have answer your question in the edited question description. There is no error in the console. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There’s a bit of redundancy in your code; `placeholder` should not be manually added and removed.

```
$("#searcher").on("input", function () {
    var text = $("#searcher").val();
    // If the text is empty, hide the keyboard and blur the search text box.
    if (text === "") return;
    // Do a search in middle layer.
    fuseDoSearch(text);
    // Call this function to refresh the UI.
    refreshUI();
}).on(mobile ? "touchstart" : "mousedown", function() {
    // There is a bug in mobile devices that you have to hold the input
    // box for a while to get focus of the input box. So use this to force
    // the input box to get focus when clicked on.
    $("#searcher").focus();
});
```

And that should fix your problem, too – the `return` will stop the search from continuing with an empty string. I’m pretty sure that’s what’s breaking things.